# HTTP Status 404 - in eclipse while calling send redirect method

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I tried a simple servlet program which uses a `sendredirect` method in eclipse. 
Here is its code:

```
public class Sendredirectmethod extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
        pw.close();
    }

}
```

Now when I am running on my tomcat server, I am getting error as shown in the screenshot url http://postimg.org/image/f9rdwwss7/ .

How to resolve this problem? What happened while executing it?

Comment: You should dig out a stacktrace from your tomcat and paste here.

Comment: Let's see your web.xml.

Comment: ok its working fine i forgot to update web.xml but still i have doubt why web.xml is not getting automatically updated with tomcat 7 it used to happen with earlier versions of tomcat